# JAX-RS Send File / InputStream from Client to RESTful Web Service

Tags: java, forms, web-services, rest, jax-rs

I have to implement a RESTful Web Service which accepts xml-files.
I have a Client-Application and a Server-Application using Jersey.

Problem: I have to send a File from my Client to my RESTful Web Service.

Client-Code:

```
File file = new File("Path_to_file.xml");
InputStream in = new FileInputStream(file);
Response response = this.client
                        .target("http://localhost:8080/rest/import/upload")
                        .request(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
                        .post(Entity.xml(in));
```

Server-Code:

```
@Post
@Path("/upload")
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM)
@Produces
public Response upload(@FormParam("file") File file) {
   ...code to validate File ...
}
```

I cannot import: `javax.ws.rs.core.Form`,`javax.ws.rs.core.FormDataMultiPart`.
Every answer I could find so far is telling me to implement these Classes.

Hopyfully, someone can help me :)

Greetz, Paddaels

Comment: What errors are you getting?

Comment: try to import : **javax.ws.rs-api-2.1-m07.jar**

Comment: And here a [link](https://coderanch.com/t/551977/java/Jersey-RESTful-web-service-post) may can help you with the other request

Answer (score 0):

You can use  [JAX-RS Client API](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/client/package-summary.html) then do doing something like

```
  public String findUserByUsername(String username) {
    Response res = userTarget
            .resolveTemplate("username", username)
            .request("application/json").get();
    return res.readEntity(String.class);
}
```